# What does "multiple scopes" mean in when talking about MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) and .NET 4.5?

Tags: mef, .net-4.5

In [What's new in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) microsoft says that MEF will now support "multiple scopes". What does this mean? I can't find documentation on that anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you question is anwered fully in this blog: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/12/19/sharing-with-compositionscopedefinition-in-mef2-alok.aspx